# How to handle text notifications in UIAutomation?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, notifications, ui-automation

In iOS app,I am changing the text of the label.In `Objective C`,for text change there are `delegates`. How to handle the same scenario using `UIAutomation`?Are there any notifications, we get for the text change in `UIAutomation` ?

I have label and this label text is set in the app.Is there any way to get notified in `UIAutomation` or any script when the label text changes ?

Is there any alternative to observe text notifications in iOS Automation?

Comment: check this [link](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation). hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are testing iOS application using UIAutomation. You can control your data, make it data driven so when pop up comes up you know the data

Comment: iamMobile: Can You elaborate this or could you please provide me any example or link

Comment: Ram, Here is the solution. 1. Accept your Test data in txt format or in XML format from user (QA team) 2. Write a shell or python script to accept this file and generate java script file at runtime. Example. data.txt file can contain key/value pair E.g. user_email = xyz@abc.com  and write a script to convert this txt file to js file (For simple scenarios you don't need to do so)